# How call RestFul Webservice from JSP page and use the JSON object?

Tags: jsp, rest

I have a restful web services which returns a JSON object. I need to call that Webservices in JSP and do some processing so that the JSON object content can be shown to the client side.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JQuery AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ as if you do it in HTML and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Another method. You can generate JavaScript client by WADL.